# Headphones plugged in text messages make no noise

Tags: iphone, ios

I am running iOS 10.  So when I receive calls with my headphones plugged in I get a ringer.

But when I get a text message with my headphones plugged in I get nothing.

Both "Do Not Disturb" & "Silented" from the orange side knob are disabled.

How can I make the text messages make a audible room noise even with headphones plugged in?

I am the latest supported version on my iPhone 5.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you get alert tones when you receive texts without headphones plugged in?

Comment: @user3052786 No.  Considering the SE app just displayed this message on my phone with no beep then the answer is no.

Comment: So the question's more general then? You get no alert tones at all regardless of whether you have headphones plugged in or not? Couple more troubleshooting questions: 1. Does pressing the volume buttons on the side adjust "Volume" or "Ringer"? 2. Do alert tones play when you get texts/notifications when your phone is locked?

Comment: @user3052786 The question is what it is.  I don't care about any notification besides my text messages.  If you fix the other issues then bonus points but I could care less. "headphones" because headphones are plugged in.  No alert tons play regardless of locked or unlocked.

Comment: Do they play through your headphones? Is anything else playing through your headphones? Edit: wait, you didn't answer my question, are you saying no sound plays for text notifications even without headphones plugged in?

Comment: @user3052786 the ringer plays in both the notifications only through the headphones.

Comment: Usually the first step in troubleshooting is to make sure you have all OS updates applied. Are you willing you update to the latest iOS version, 11.3.1?

Comment: @fsb for the iPhone 5 iOS 10.3.3 is the last supported version to my knowledge.

Comment: That is the expected behavior, and I'm pretty sure there's no way to change that, I'm afraid. If you have headphones plugged in (or any other audio device for that matter, e.g. bluetooth speakers), the ringer will play from both the phone and the headphones, but other alert tones will only play through the headphones.

Comment: @user3052786 this is not consistent behavior with let's say a bluetooth device.

Comment: OK, your question didn't indicate the iPhone type.

Comment: It is, by default. With a bluetooth speaker, you can control whether audio is routed through bluetooth or through the built in speakers, but unless you do that, it behaves the same way. Ringers from incoming calls play on both, but notifications play on only the bluetooth speaker. (Initially, anyway)

Comment: But hey, you're on iOS 10.3.3! If you jailbreak, anything's possible. If that's an option for you, of course.

Comment: @fsb I beg to differ, haha. There are definitely periods of time usually after major releases when an update may actually cause new issues. Maybe checking the version you are running might be a better first step.